# Python 2.7: L += branch_length results in NameError: name 'L' not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

It's a populations genetics program handed out by my professors and modified by the students.

Basically it's supposed to simulate the expected number of mutations twenty times with a given sample, population, and mutation rate (u). However, a critical piece is the total branch length (L), which is the sum of the various smaller branch lengths (branch_length). However, when I define L as below, it keeps coming back with the error:

```
  L += branch_length  
NameError: name 'L' is not defined
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, since tree_depth is defined the same way and works flawlessly.

Here's the full code:

```
from random import expovariate
from pgen import poidev
K = 77       # sample size (number of gene copies)
twoN = 5000  # population size
u = .001

tree_depth = 0.0 # age of last common ancestor in generations

# Each pass through loop deals with one coalescent interval.

for A in range(20):
    while K > 1:
        h = K*(K-1)/(2.0*twoN) # hazard of a coalescent event
        t = expovariate(h)       # time until next coalescent event
        tree_depth += t
        branch_length = t*K
        K -= 1
        L += branch_length
    S = poidev(u*L)
    print "Simulation:", A+1, "Total Mutations:", S
print "Total tree depth (L):", L, "generations"
```

Am I just missing something really, really obvious? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`L += x` adds x to the existing L, but you haven't initialized L.  Presumably, you want `L = 0` somewhere at the top of your file.

Comment: Working like a charm. I knew it was something simple.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `L = 0` before doing `L += x`.

In general, before modifying you need to define the variable. For assignment, there is no problem because python will infer the type for you.

Some examples:

```
>>> a += 0 #Invalid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> a = 5 #Valid
>>> a += 0 #Now it's valid, because a is defined.
>>> 
>>> my_list.append(5) #Invalid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'my_list' is not defined
>>> my_list = [] 
>>> my_list.append(5) #Now valid
>>> my_list
[5]
>>>
>>> my_list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4] #Valid, because it's an assignment.
```